# Type Error in get_wsgi_application() in Django 2.x with python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, wsgi

I am migrating a web application from Django 1.9 to 2.0.2. 
The code is

```
import os
import sys

path = '/mypath'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Myapplication.settings")


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

However, if I try to execute this, I get an error:

```
File "/home/.../wsgi.py", line 29, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/home/.../virtual/lagerthree/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
return WSGIHandler()
File "/home/.../lagerthree/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 140, in __init__
self.load_middleware()
File "/home/.../virtual/lagerthree/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

According to StackExchange and other sites, the cause of this error is the deprecation of certain things from 1.x to 2.x and the solution is the `MiddlewareMixin` which should be used like this: `class FOOMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin): ...`

My `MIDDLEWARE` settings are:

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'users.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware')
```

But I don't have any classes and also, the `get_wsgi_application()` function should still work, as far as I know.
How should I solve this?

Comment: is your code tabbed right?? it looks like an error with tabs and spacing

Comment: It should be tabbed right, but the tabs were messed up when I pasted the code into SE...

Comment: What is your `MIDDLEWARE` setting?

Comment: updated the post

Comment: I'm also facing the same. @LizzAlice can you share how did you fix the problem?

Comment: @iamrameshkumar Have you fixed the issue? I could see the same issue while migrationg django 1.10 to 3.2.

Comment: @RameshPasham I don't exactly remember, but it has to do with the middleware settings and middleware versions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the debug_toolbar, as the only one third-party library.
Anyway , try to update django_debug_toolbar to lastest version.