# Python : Django TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

I'm porting a django application from 1.x to 2.1 and got stuck with the error that says "TypeError: object() takes no parameters". I'm trying to solve the problem for quite a while but not even got a clue even after days of debugging and searching online

**Installed apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'timezone_field',
    'axes',
    'humans',
    'boxes',
    'pages',
]
```

**Middleware settings:**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]
```

There are no problems with the indentation,

> celery version : 4.2.1
>   raven version : 6.9.0
>   django version : 2.1

**Here is my wsgi.py**

```
import os
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.wsgi import Sentry

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
application=Sentry(get_wsgi_application())
```

**Here is an excerpt from the error log**

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed   
File "/app/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
        application=Sentry(get_wsgi_application())   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
        return WSGIHandler()   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 136, in __init__
        self.load_middleware()   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 36, in load_middleware
        mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

**Error after using CustomSentry :**

```
in <module>
    application = CustomSentry(get_wsgi_application())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 36, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I tried to catch the exceptions using ExceptionMiddleware, now I'm getting the following error:

```
application = CustomSentry(get_wsgi_application())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 85, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'application'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add the file `/app/wsgi.py` ?

Comment: @JPG my wsgi contains nothing but the code mentioned in the question.

Comment: Updated the thread with my middleware settings

Comment: update the question with your `INSTALLED_APPS` please; and your `MIDDLEWARE` list is not in the right order. `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',` should be _above_ `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',`

Comment: Included my INSTALLED_APPS settings in the post. There is no difference in the error log after moving up the django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware

Comment: I would suggest adding a breakpoint (or print statement) before line 36 in `django/utils/deprecation.py` to inspect the variable `middleware_path`.

Comment: Have you checked your versions of middlewares? It looks like whitenoise would be the culprit. Did you `pip install --upgrade` it to a version that is compatible with django 2.1?

Comment: @LaurentS Whitenoise version is 4.0 and is compatible with django 2.1 as per the documentation (http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable)

Comment: The error persists even after commenting out whitenoise middleware in settings.

Comment: As is mentioned above, I would try to figure out which middleware is causing the problem, either with a breakpoint, or by adding a `print` statement just above the line that causes problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003357/type-error-in-get-wsgi-application-in-django-2-x-with-python3 this refers to a similar problem but there is no answer posted.

Comment: No it's proper in the actual code. I think there is some formatting problem when I copy pasted the code here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error indicates that you have an old-style middleware in your middleware list. Old-style middlewares did not receive an argument upon instantiation, while new-style middlewares receive a handler.

Now, according to your settings, the only non-Django middleware is whitenoise, but you say that the error persists even after commenting that out.

Here are some suggestion to help you figure out what's going on:

- As I have commented, add a breakpoint or print statement to the Django source to figure out which middleware causes the issue.
- Make sure that the settings file you are editing is the one that is actually used.
- Use the Python shell to inspect the actual value of the `MIDDLEWARE` setting:

  ```
  $ python manage.py shell
  >>> from django.conf import settings
  >>> settings.MIDDLEWARE
  ...
  ```

Comment: inspecting settings doesn't give me any different result. I will try putting breakpoints in Django source and find out which middleware causes the problem and I think that is the only way to a solution here after.

Comment: @Ram Where was the problem?

Answer (score 4):

try this in you `/app/wsgi.py` module,

```
import os
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.wsgi import Sentry

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class CustomSentry(MiddlewareMixin, Sentry):
    pass


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
application = CustomSentry(get_wsgi_application())
```

**References**
1. [object() takes no parameters in django 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457381/object-takes-no-parameters-in-django-1-10)
2. [Django exception middleware: TypeError: object() takes no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232606/django-exception-middleware-typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters)

Comment: Now I'm getting the same error starting at "application = CustomSentry(get_wsgi_application())"

Comment: I guess it's something to deal with the get_wsgi_application(), you must be able to reproduce the error if you just create a wsgi.py in a project with the same code as above and try running it with the mentioned dependencies (celery 4.2.1, raven version : 6.9.0, django version : 2.1 & python 3.5)

Comment: Related to the error "Since you are using the new MIDDLEWARE settings, your Middleware class must accept a get_response argument" as said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232606/django-exception-middleware-typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters. If it is my own class I could have added get_response argument but the wsgi is actually a library and I don't have any control on it also it's in the latest version.

Comment: Is it something related to the order of the MIDDLE_WARE settings?, I tried the possible combinations as much as I can.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behaviour :(

Comment: @Ram Can you find out which middleware class is causing the problem by commenting out the middleware class from settings.py?

Comment: I'm trying various possible options. I will post it if I could find anything.

Comment: Can you add the whitenoise version ?

Comment: whitenoise version is 4.0

Comment: Did you tried to run the server by commenting out whitenoise middleware ?

Comment: I tried to catch the exceptions by adding a ExceptionMiddleware, I'm getting the error "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'application'", Updated the same in the post.

Comment: I reproduced the error by adding a custom middleware class as mentioned in my references-1. Is there any way you could share the project?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003357/type-error-in-get-wsgi-application-in-django-2-x-with-python3 refers to a similar problem but there is no answer posted.